# Updating custom attributes in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I´ve got a little problem updating custom attibutes in Active Directory and hope you guys can help me.

So far I´m getting the attributes updated but it sends the whole line out of my csv file instead of just one value.

OK... Here´s how my csv Looks like:

```
PERSONALNUMMER;GESCHLECHT;NACHNAME;VORNAME;EMAIL;MOBIL;TEL;BEZIRK;VORGESETZER;ZINR;ZINAME;SPESENHOEHE;KOSTENSTELLE;VBART;COLLECTION;
AA871;W;Mustermann;Max;max.mustermann@contoso.com;+49123456789;+492345678901;22559;A0C57;0000000031;Maxine Mustermann;01;0010076540;VB;0
```

And this is what is imported into my AD Attribute:

```
@{PERSONALNUMMER=AA871; GESCHLECHT=W; NACHNAME=Mustermann; VORNAME=Max; EMAIL=max.mustermann@contoso.com; MOBIL=+49123456789; TEL=++492345678901; BEZIRK=22559; VORGESETZER=A0C57; ZINR=0000000031; ZINAME=Maxine Mustermann; SPESENHOEHE=01; KOSTENSTELLE=0010076540; VBART=VB; COLLECTION=0}.Collection
```

Ok... And now the code snippet which is doing this:

```
$users = Import-Csv $FullDestPath -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($user in $users) {
IF ($user.Collection -ne '') {Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.PERSONALNUMMER)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=intern,DC=berendsohn,DC=com" | Set-ADUser -replace @{bAGCollection="$user.Collection"}}
 Else {Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.PERSONALNUMMER)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=intern,DC=contoso,DC=com" |Set-ADUser -replace @{bAGCollection=""}} 
}
```

It would be great if you guys can help me here to Import just the value for Collection instead of importing the whole variable $user.

Comment: Your question looks incomplete, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ralf. In the CSV is a value for Collection - in this case 0 - and I want to update a custom Attribute bAGCollection with it instead of the string you see in my post

Comment: `@{bAGCollection="$user.Collection"}` -> `@{bAGCollection="$($user.Collection)"}`

Comment: Thank you Mathias!! That worked!!!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen please write that up in an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the string you use:

```
Set-ADUser -replace @{bAGCollection="$user.Collection"}
```

will result in the parser expanding `$user` and treating `.Collection` as a literal string. Enclose the property reference using the subexpression operator `$()`:

```
Set-ADUser -replace @{bAGCollection="$($user.Collection)"}
```